# Login Redirect Error - $user->roles

Tags: login

I'm doing a simple login redirect to a custom admin page using the following code:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    if ( is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles )  || in_array( 'shop_manager', $user->roles ) ) {
            return admin_url( 'admin.php?page=welcome-page.php' );
        } else {
            return admin_url();
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

However, I am getting the error:

Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$roles

the line it refers to is `if ( is_array( $user->roles ) ) {`

this seems to be the recommended way in the WordPress docs - what could be going wrong here?

Comment: I remember having difficulties with this myself with one project - I seem to have this in the code which seems roundabout but not sure why else I would have put it in like so:             `global $user;
            
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            
            $userObj = get_userdata($user_id);` to then get the object properly. You can then `$userObj->roles` to get roles array.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at PhpDocs for `login_redirect` filter I found out that the third param could be a `WP_Error` object instead of a `WP_User`:

> $user WP_User object if login was successful, WP_Error object otherwise.

So a working code sample for you would be:

```
function dls160216_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        // do redirects on successful login
        if ( $user->has_cap( 'administrator' ) || $user->has_cap( 'shop_manager' ) ) {
            return admin_url( 'admin.php?page=welcome-page.php' );
        } else {
            return admin_url();
        }
    } else {
        // display errors, basically
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'dls160216_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Note that I used `has_cap` method. It's more future-proof and allows for better filtering. Can verify a capability or a role.

Answer (score 0):

**I think the answer is great Dan Ștefancu.
this is my code and it looked great**

```
    // si el usuario es un administrador, redirigir a la página de administración
    if ( is_array( $user) && in_array( 'administrator', $user) ) {
        return admin_url();
    }
    // si el usuario es un editor, redirigir a la página de edición
    elseif ( is_array( $user) && in_array( 'editor', $user) ) {
        return admin_url();
    }
    // si el usuario es un autor, redirigir a la página de escritura
    elseif ( is_array( $user) && in_array( 'author', $user) ) {
        return home_url( 'PaginaInicio.php' );
    }
    // si el usuario es un colaborador, redirigir a la página de colaboración
    elseif ( is_array( $user) && in_array( 'contributor', $user) ) {
        return home_url( 'PaginaInicio.php' );
    }
    // si el usuario es un suscriptor, redirigir a la página de suscripción
    elseif ( is_array( $user) && in_array( 'subscriber', $user) ) {
        return home_url( 'PaginaInicio.php' );
    }
    // de lo contrario, redirigir a la página principal
    return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'dls160216_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

**page where you support me
https://www.pluginsweb.es/redirigir-despues-acceder-wordpress/**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/265718)